# How to dequeue the smallest element from queue in C

Tags: c, queue, priority-queue

I created a queue and enqueue some values. Then, I want to dequeue the smallest value from the queue. I got the smallest value by linear search. But I don't know how to deal with the front and rear after I find the smallest value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void enQueue(int);
void deQueue();

int items[SIZE], front = -1, rear = -1;

int main() {
  enQueue(3);
  enQueue(5);
  enQueue(4);
  enQueue(1);
  enQueue(2);

  printf("Deleted value is %d\n",deQueue());

  return 0;
}

void enQueue(int value) {
  if (rear == SIZE - 1)
    printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
  else {
    if (front == -1)
      front = 0;
    rear++;
    items[rear] = value;
    printf("\nInserted -> %d", value);
  }
}

int deQueue() {
  if (front == -1)
    exit(1);
  else {
    int min=0;
    for(int i=front;i<rear;i++){
        if(items[min]>items[i])
           min=i;
    }
    int value=items[min];

    //What should I do then for front and rear in order to remove the deleted value
    

    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not just the `front` and `rear` you need to deal with. You need to compact all the entries after the removed one. That is, copy each entry after the removed one to the index before the original index. Then reduce the rear by one. Nothing needs to be done to the front unless it was removed to leave an empty queue in which case it needs to be set to -1. That's the algorithm in words. Now try it on a piece of paper and then try to code it.

Comment: If you always want the smallest item in the queue, you should implement a [min-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
items[min]=items[rear];
rear--;
```

Comment: That's ideal if `items` is unordered, but a queue is normally ordered so that could cause problems in that case.